# How to add javascript to a page from another page

Tags: javascript, wicket

I have two classes: `ItemPanel.java` and `Declaration.java.` Each time an item panel is created I want javascript to append to the head of Declaration.html not ItemPanel.html.

On my ItemPanel.java, should I have something like this:

```
add(new AbstractBehavior() {
   @Override public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
        super.renderHead(response);
        String js = "alert(\"hello\");"
        response.renderOnDomReadyJavascript(js, Declaration.java);
    }
});
```

So my question is: if I have lots of classes and html pages, and I add a javascript on a page where there is no header, how does wicket treat this? Does it find the header from other related classes? I'm not sure, I have tried it and it doesn't seem to append when I instantiate an object that doesn't have a corresponding html page with a head tag.

Comment: Which Wicket version you are using?

Comment: if i am not wrong you have a page and few panels attached to that panel(where their is no head tag in .html file for panel), right ?

Comment: @Martin Strejc - I'm using 1.4.9 

Ashish - I have a page and I add panels to that page, there is no head tag in the panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning your question is a bit confusing because ibe the title you ask to add JS from one page to another but in your question it seems that `ItemPanel` is a `Panel` and `Declaration` is a `Page`.

So if it is like this and you render some JavaScript in a Panel like you've shown it will be rendered in the `<head></head>` section of your `Declaration` page. Even if your `Page` in html will have no  `<head></head>` section Wicket will generate an empty  `<head></head>` section. So if you render some JavaScript in a `Panel` it will be rendered in the  `<head></head>` section of the containing `Page`.